# Angular route parameters

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I want to have 2 routes like that:

- `user/:userIdProfile`
- `user/:userIdSettings`

Is it possible?

If so, how can I do it ?

If not, do you have a best alternative?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible for angular to make a difference between two dynamic route cases.
You should either use one route and filter the parameter for each case. Or, the more logical way, to have two routes:

```
user/profile/:id
user/settings/:id
```

you could  also try this:

```
user/:id/profile
user/:id/settings
```

Comment: Thank you Eliav. It's good to know it. The query params solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use Query Params.

```
goToUserProfile(id) {
  this.router.navigate(['/user'], { queryParams: { userIdProfile: '1'} });
}

goToUserSettings(id) {
  this.router.navigate(['/user'], { queryParams: { userIdSettings: '1'} });
}
```

or

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user']" [queryParams]="{ userIdSettings: '1'}">
  Go to user Settings
</a>
```

and then in your .ts user Component

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
         // Check if there are more than one query params.
         if(Object.keys(params).length > 1) return; 
         // if( params. userIdProfile){ //do whatever you want }
         // else if( params. userIdSettings){ //do whatever you want }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Guiditox, thhis worked for me